# Make variable sum of two other variables after change

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

Please look at the following code. There is an issue in it which I am struggling to understand:

```
let sideCount = 0;
let mealCount = 0;
let itemCount = sideCount + mealCount;

const pizzaOrder = ({size, crustType, topping, quantity}) => {
    quantity = Math.round(parseInt(quantity));
    mealCount += quantity;
    if (topping === "") {
        console.log(`Order: ${quantity} ${size.toTitleCase()} ${crustType.toLowerCase()} crust plain cheese pizza`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Order: ${quantity} ${size.toTitleCase()} ${crustType.toLowerCase()} crust ${topping} pizza`);
    }
    console.log(`Meal Count after ordering ${quantity} pizzas: ${mealCount}`);
    console.log(`Current item count: ${itemCount}`);        
};
```

(There's more, but this is what is important for the question)

I have looked all over StackOverflow for referencing and pass by value or pass by reference, but I couldn't find anything that solved my problem.

When I update `mealCount`, it doesn't change the value of `itemCount`. How do I fix this?

```
Order: 10 Medium thin crust pepperoni pizza 
Meal Count after ordering 10 pizzas: 10 
Current item count: 0 
Order: 3 burgers with Relish 
Meal Count after ordering burger: 13 
Current item count: 0 
Meal Count: 0 Side Count: 0 
Meal Count: 0 
Side Count: 0 
Meal Count: 0 
Side Count: 0 
Your total is $0.00. Enjoy your meal!
```

Comment: Have you called the pizza order function and then logged the itemCount?

Comment: Yes, I have. It shows 0.

Comment: There is no such thing like a reference to a variable in JS, what you are asking for is not possible. Make an `itemCount()` function that computes the sum on every call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the `mealCount` in each function, I returned the `mealCount` or `sideCount` or `drinkCount` in an object, like so

```
return {mealCount: quantity};
```

Then, I used the `Array.prototype.reduce()` method on the `orders` parameter of the `groupOrder()` function, a function that you call, pass an array of function calls to the food orders, with the food order and price calculations nested inside of it

```
let mealCount = orders.reduce((av, cv) => {
    if (cv.hasOwnProperty('mealCount')) {
        return {mealCount: av.mealCount + cv.mealCount};
    }
    return {mealCount: av.mealCount + 0};
}, {mealCount: 0}).mealCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Code is interpreted (evaluated) sequentially.

When you write:
let itemCount = sideCount + mealCount;

You actually assign value of sideCount + mealCount to itemCount. At the very moment, sideCount and mealCount have value of "0", hence itemCount equals "0".

You calling function pizzaOrder and changing mealCount (inside this function) won't make javascript reevaluate once more addition of mentioned line (let itemCount = sideCount + mealCount).

Literally, pizzaOrder function does not affect variable "itemCount" at all.

One problem solution would be to add line:
"itemCount = sideCount + mealCount" inside of pizzaOrder function, specifically under the line: "mealCount += quantity;".

So, your code would look like:

```
const pizzaOrder = ({size, crustType, topping, quantity}) => {
    quantity = Math.round(parseInt(quantity));
    mealCount += quantity;
    totalCount = mealCount + sideCount;
    if (topping === "") {
        console.log(`Order: ${quantity} ${size.toTitleCase()} ${crustType.toLowerCase()} crust plain cheese pizza`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Order: ${quantity} ${size.toTitleCase()} ${crustType.toLowerCase()} crust ${topping} pizza`);
    }
    console.log(`Meal Count after ordering ${quantity} pizzas: ${mealCount}`);
    console.log(`Current item count: ${itemCount}`);        
};
```

Comment: I have tons of other functions like pizza order. Does this mean I have to put this line in everyone of them, or is there a work around

Comment: @Marvin Make a function `updateCount` that is called from each of them :-) You will have to (more or less explicitly) do the recalculation either every time you change one of the input values or every time you need the output value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the "state" of your order you might want to use an object that can be exposed wherever you might need it:

```
const count = {
sideCount: 0,
mealCount: 0,
itemCount() {
    return this.sideCount + this.mealCount
  }
}

const pizzaOrder = ({size, crustType, topping, quantity}) => {
quantity = Math.round(parseInt(quantity));
count.mealCount += quantity;
if (topping === "") {
    console.log(`Order: ${quantity} ${size.toTitleCase()} ${crustType.toLowerCase()} crust plain cheese pizza`);
} else {
    console.log(`Order: ${quantity} ${size} ${crustType.toLowerCase()} crust ${topping} pizza`);
}
console.log(`Meal Count after ordering ${quantity} pizzas: ${count.mealCount}`);
console.log(`Current item count: ${count.itemCount()}`);        
};
console.log(count.itemCount()) // 0

pizzaOrder({size: 'asd', crustType: 'asd', topping: 'asd', quantity: 1})

console.log(count.itemCount()) // 1
```

As the other people mentioned your code won't work like that.
Hope this helps.

Comment: With an object, you could even make it a getter property.

Comment: Does it have to be a method? Can I make it a property?